# QPushButton is not changing the background-color proper

Tags: css, qt, qt4, qt4.8

I have a problem with a QPushButton.
I use QT 4.8 and the Designer.

I configured the button to be "flat" and "checkable".
The button should be red if not checked and green if checked.
To style the button I use a stylesheet.

```
      QPushButton:default{
         background-color: red;
             color: red;
      }

      QPushButton:checked{
         background-color: green;
             color: black;
      }
```

Now the problem. If the button is unchecked it is gray. When I press the button he turns green like it should.
I tried different other pseudo-states, like !checked, or tried to change to a normal button. But it's always the same. In default state the stylesheet isn't working. If I presse, hover or what ever the button it is changing like I want it.

Any body encountered the same problem and has a solution?

To explain it a little bit further. The color attribute is working correct.
The text is always red, except I push the button then it's black.
So the style sheet is in use but, just the background-color attribute is not working.

I tried different styles, like motif, cde, cleanlooks etc and it's always the same.

Comment: If your button is `flat` why you don't use `:flat` selector?

Comment: I tested a lot of different pseudo-states ... the flat / checked combination was under it. Not working

Comment: Any combination of `:flat:checked:hover:default`? :) Did you try `::indicator` selector? Btw, there are no Qt documentation, that says that `:checked` state is supported for `QPushButton`. Why do you think that it should be supported? **I propose you to customize QCheckBox to look like QPushBotton.** It's very easy.

Comment: I tested not every combination but a lot. The Qt Style Sheets Reference http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html says that QPushButton "Supports the :default, :flat, :checked pseudo states."

Comment: Sometimes you have to change border to 0/whatever you need in order to make background work properly. "Normal state" selector for QPushButton is just QPushButton { background-color: red; } then you put your state dependent CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this in QPushButton Class Reference. "This property's default is false. If this property is set, most styles will not paint the button background unless the button is being pressed. setAutoFillBackground() can be used to ensure that the background is filled using the QPalette::Button brush." Because of this I found the following solution.

First of all I kept the style sheet option for checked

```
     QPushButton:checked{
         background-color: green.
     }
```

The I used a palette and set the background color and the setAutoFillBackground function.

```
     palette_red->setColor(window.button->backgroundRole(), QColor(255, 0, 0, 127));
     window.button->setAutoFillBackground(true);
 window.button->setPalette(*palette_red);
```

I use the toggle signal to catch changes.
When the button is toggle is TRUE the style sheet starts working.
To not get double (green over red) colors the setAutoFillBackground has to be turned off again.

```
     window.button->setAutoFillBackground(false);
```

The not toggled state is nearly the same.
I needed to turn on the setAutoFillBackground and set the palette again.

```
     window.button->setAutoFillBackground(true);
     window.button->setPalette(*palette_red);
```

It's a solution, it works but I am still open for further inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Not all platforms support styled button backgrounds. What platform are you running on? What is the class name of the style in use?

```
qDebug() << qApp->style()->metaObject()->className();
```

Comment: I use linux mint 15.

I get QGtkStyle on qDebug.